# Learning to write functions in R

Tags: r, function

I am at the point with R where I would like to start writing my own functions because I tend to need to do the same things over and over. However, I am struggling to see how I can generalize what I write. Looking at source code has not helped me learn very well because often it seems that .Internal or .Primitive functions (or other commands I do not know) are used extensively. I would like to simply start by turning my normal copy-pasted solutions into functions - fancier things can come later!

As an example: I do a lot of data formatting that requires doing some operation, and then filling in a data frame with zeros for all other combinations that did not have any data (e.g., years that did not have observations and were therefore not originally recorded, etc). I need to do this over and over for different data sets that have different sets of variables, but the idea and implementation is always the same.

My non-function way of solving this has been (for a specific implementation and minimal example):

```
df <- data.frame(County = c(1, 45, 57),
                 Year = c(2002, 2003, 2003),
                 Level = c("Mean", "Mean", "Mean"),
                 Obs = c(1.4, 1.9, 10.2))

#Create expanded version of data frame
Counties <- seq(from = 1, to = 77, by = 2)
Years <- seq(from = 1999, to = 2014, by = 1)
Levels <- c("Max", "Mean")
Expansion <- expand.grid(Counties, Years, Levels)
Expansion[4] <- 0
colnames(Expansion) <- colnames(df)

#Merge and order them so that the observed value is on top
df_full <- merge(Expansion, df, all = TRUE)
df_full$duplicate <- with(df_full,
                          paste(Year, County, Level))

df_full <- df_full[order(df_full$Year,
                         df_full$County,
                         df_full$Level,
                         -abs(df_full$Obs)), ]

#Deduplicate by taking the first that shows up (the observation)
df_full <- df_full[ !duplicated(df_full$duplicate), ]
df_full$duplicate <- NULL
```

I would like to generalize this so that I could somehow put in a data frame (and probably select the columns I need to order by since that sometimes changes) and then get the expanded version out. My first implementation consisted of a function with too many arguments (the data-frame and then all the column names I wanted to order/expand.grid by) and it also did not work:

```
gridExpand <- function(df, col1, col2=NULL, col3=NULL, measure){
  #Started with "Expansion" being a global outside of the function 
  #It is identical the first part of the above code
  ex <- merge(Expansion, df, all = TRUE)
  ex$dupe <- with(ex,
                 paste(col1, col2, col3))
   ex <- ex[order(with(ex,
                       col1, col2, col3, -abs(measure)))]
   ex <- ex[ !duplicated(ex$dupe)]
   ex <- subset(ex, select = -(dupe))  
}

df_full <- gridExpand(df, Year, County, Level, Obs)

Error in paste(col1, col2, col3) : object 'Year' not found
```

I am assuming that this did not work because R has no way to know where `'Year'` came from. I could potentially try  `paste(df, "$Year")` but it would create `"df$Year"` which obviously will not work. And I do not ever see anyone else do this in their functions so clearly I am missing how it is that people reference things in data frame relevant functions.

I would ideally like to know of some resources that could help with thinking about generalization, or if someone can point me in the right direction to solving this particular problem I think it might help me see what I am doing wrong. I do not know of a better way to ask for help - I have been trying to read tutorials on writing functions for about 3 months and it is not clicking.

Comment: Asking for "resources" isn't really a very specific programming question. It would help if you could edit your question to make your specific programming challenge clear. Describing how any function should be written is way too broad a topic and is often a matter of opinion. When you are describing a problem that "didn't work" include relevant error messages and/or describe the result you were expecting and how what you got differed.

Comment: Okay, I tried a bit of editing - hopefully a little more clear. This is a broad topic. I do not really care about the downvote - I really want to learn this and I am willing to keep trying to edit this so that hopefully someone can help me. If other people can see the logic of the mistake I am making in this example and can point out at least small ways to improve my reasoning, that would be a godsend. For instance, if the function is too big and I should break it up (I think so, but don't know how) or there are better ways to reference data frame columns as a parameter, etc

Answer (score 9, accepted):

At a glance, the biggest thing that you can do is to **not** use non-standard-evaluation shortcuts inside your functions: things like `$`, `subset()` and `with()`. These are functions intended for convenient interactive use, not extensible programmatic use. (See, e.g., the *Warning* in `?subset` which should probably be added to `?with`, `fortunes::fortune(312)`, `fortunes::fortune(343)`.)

```
fortunes::fortune(312)
```

> The problem here is that the $ notation is a magical shortcut and like
>   any other magic if used incorrectly is likely to do the programmatic
>   equivalent of turning yourself into a toad.    -- Greg Snow (in
>   response to a user that wanted to access a column whose name is stored
>         in `y` via `x$y` rather than `x[[y]]`)
>         R-help (February 2012)

```
fortunes::fortune(343)
```

> Sooner or later most R beginners are bitten by this all too convenient shortcut. As an R
>   newbie, think of R as your bank account: overuse of $-extraction can lead to undesirable
>   consequences. It's best to acquire the `[[` and `[` habit early.
>      -- Peter Ehlers (about the use of $-extraction)
>            R-help (March 2013)

When you start writing functions that work on data frames, if you need to reference column names you should pass them in as strings, and then use `[` or `[[` to get the column based on the string stored in a variable name. This is the simplest way to make functions flexible with user-specified column names. For example, here's a simple stupid function that tests if a data frame has a column of the given name:

```
does_col_exist_1 = function(df, col) {
    return(!is.null(df$col))
}

does_col_exist_2 = function(df, col) {
    return(!is.null(df[[col]])
    # equivalent to df[, col]
}
```

These yield:

```
does_col_exist_1(mtcars, col = "jhfa")
# [1] FALSE
does_col_exist_1(mtcars, col = "mpg")
# [1] FALSE

does_col_exist_2(mtcars, col = "jhfa")
# [1] FALSE
does_col_exist_2(mtcars, col = "mpg")
# [1] TRUE
```

The first function is wrong because `$` doesn't evaluate what comes after it, no matter what value I set `col` to when I call the function, `df$col` will look for a column literally named `"col"`. The brackets, however, will evaluate `col` and see "oh hey, `col` is set to `"mpg"`, let's look for a column of that name."

If you want lots more understanding of this issue, I'd recommend the [Non-Standard Evaluation Section of Hadley Wickham's Advanced R book](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html).

I'm not going to re-write and debug your functions, but if I wanted to my first step would be to remove all `$`, `with()`, and `subset()`, replacing with `[`. There's a pretty good chance that's all you need to do.

Comment: I wish I could accept this twice - once for providing me exactly the help I needed, and again for introducing me to the fortunes package...