# Variable names as strings in tagged vectors

Tags: r

I need to transform a data frame variable in a function, and the target variable name is specified in one of the function parameters:

```
myfunction = function(varname, df)
{
   transform(varname=log(df[, varname]), df)
}
```

A similar problem:

```
var="a"
> d = data.frame(eval(var) = runif(10, 1, 1000))
Error: unexpected '=' in "d = data.frame(eval(var) ="
> d = data.frame(as.name(eval(var)) = runif(10, 1, 1000))
Error: unexpected '=' in "d = data.frame(as.name(eval(var)) ="
```

How can I make transform() work?

Comment: You don't show any `transform` code, but in general don't use interactive shortcut functions programmatically. I answered a question the other day [that goes into a more detail](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31061827/903061).

Comment: You can do a lot with do.call, which calls a function with a named list of arguments. But you'll have to be more specific with an example. There is no straightforward approach to what you are doing, short of constructing a string and using `eval(parse(text = mystring))` (which is almost always a bad idea)

Comment: For instance, using `transform` a better approach would be assigning a new column with`d[[var]] <- `

Comment: @DavidRobinson ok, it sounds like I should use a different approach. Please see my revised question, I'm not clear how I can make my transform() work from your last comment.

Comment: @RobertKubrick how about `df[[varname]] <- log(df[[varname]])`, then `return(df)`?

Comment: @DavidRobinson It works, thanks. That's the answer I was looking for.

Comment: @RobertKubrick Cool, I've added it to the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the column name after creating the data.frame:

```
var = "a"
d = setNames(data.frame(runif(10, 1, 1000)), var)
```

In your case, you can reassign a column with:

```
myfunction = function(varname, df)
{
    df[[varname]] <- log(df[[varname]])
    df
}
```

Comment: more concisely `setNames(data.frame(runif(10, 1, 1000)), var)`

Comment: Actually I can't create the data frame from scratch, I need to replace an existing variable with the transformed values.

Comment: @RobertKubrick Then use `[` or `[[`, not `$` or `transform()` and you'll be fine. Read the linked answer in my comment to your question.