# Use a string in R to refer to part of an object

Tags: r

I'm trying to refer to part of an object in R. I know the object exists, but when I use the string to refer to it R return an error message.

This is the code:

```
pre.s1 <- "muBE"
s1 <- capture.output(cat(c("output$sims.list$", pre.s1), sep=""))
```

if run R outputs:

```
> s1
[1] "output$sims.list$muBE"
```

using `get(s1)` returns `Error in get(s1) : object 'output$sims.list$muBE' not found`, but typing the same string directly into the console returns what the part of the object I'm looking for:

```
> output$sims.list$muBE
[1] 3.779613 3.758171 3.713178 etc... etc....
```

**How do I tell R that the string `s1` should be used to return the actual (part of the) object?**

*Note: In the end I want to be able to do
    `difference <- s1 - s2`
where `s2` is almost identical to `s1` but contains sligthly different values. Currently this returns error message: `Error in s1 - s2 : non-numeric argument to binary operator`*

Comment: You've got the same problem [as this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31060416/903061), I have an answer with a fair bit of detail. In summary, `$` is a magical shortcut that was never intended to be used with strings. `[` or `[[` are non-magical functions that work great with or without strings. Stop trying to use `$` and you'll be fine.

Comment: You can extract the value using `eval(parse(text=s1))`, but it is not a recommended way.

Comment: @akrun, thanks, that worked! Now I will go try to find a better way to do it.

Comment: @Gregor, thanks very much for your suggestion. I first tried to use `output[[sims.list]]` instead of `output$sims.list` but that didn't work. Than I figured out I should use `output[[1]]` to get that part of the object.

Comment: You have to quote the `"sims.list"`

Comment: Or, e.g., `output[["sims.list"]][[my_string]]` where `my_string = "muBE"`.

Comment: @Gregor and akrun: Wonderful, that will make it a lot more specific. Thank you!